# Python variable increment while-loop

Tags: python, variables, loops, numbers, while-loop

I'm trying to make the variable `number` increase if user guessed the right number! And continue increase the increased one if it is guessed by another user. But it's seem my `syntax` is wrong. So i really need your help. Bellow is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Filename: while.py
number = 23
running = True

while running:
    guess = int(raw_input('Enter an integer : '))

    if guess == number:
        print 'Congratulations, you guessed it. The number is now increase'
        number += 1 # Increase this so the next user won't know it!
        running = False # this causes the while loop to stop
    elif guess < number:
        print 'No, it is a little higher than that.'
    else:
        print 'No, it is a little lower than that.'
else:
    print 'The while loop is over.'
    # Do anything else you want to do here
print 'Done'
```

Comment: by `syntax error` you mean `semantic error` here?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your syntax... Maybe you'd like the loop to keep going even after guessing the number?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without "running" variable, it's not needed

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Filename: while.py
number = 23
import sys

try:
    while True:
        guess = int(raw_input('Enter an integer : '))
        if guess == number:
            print('Congratulations, you guessed it. The number is now increase')
            number += 1 # Increase this so the next user won't know it!
        elif guess < number:
            print('No, it is a little higher than that.')
        else:
            print('No, it is a little lower than that.')
except ValueError:
    print('Please write number')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit("Ok, you're finished with your game")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Filename: while.py
number = 23
running = True

while running:
    guess = int(raw_input('Enter an integer : '))

    if guess == number:
        print 'Congratulations, you guessed it. The number is now increase'
        number += 1 # Increase this so the next user won't know it!
        running = False # this causes the while loop to stop
    elif guess < number:
        print 'No, it is a little higher than that.'
    else:
        print 'No, it is a little lower than that.'

# Do anything else you want to do here
print 'Done'
```

Comment: there's no such thing as `else if` in python; neither two `else`'s in sequence