# How do I end my while loop in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am trying to create a guessing game for myself. I want to have the computer have a random number which I have to guess. Based on what I guess, it would then respond with "higher or lower" and this should keep happening before i get the right number however what has happened is that now when I put in a guess, it says higher or lower and just repeats this throughout the page. How do I end this loop and make sure that after each "higher" or "lower" i just get another change. Please find code below.

```
import random 
the_number = random.randrange(100)+ 1
guess= int(raw_input("Take a guess:  "))
tries = 1
while (guess != the_number):
   if (guess > the_number):
      print "Lower..."
      break
   elif (guess<the_number):
      print " Higher..."
      break

   elif (guess == the_number):
      print "Awesome achievement"
      break
   else:
      print "Better luck next time."
      guess = int(raw_input("Take another guess  "))
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered on numerous occasion.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, include URL.

Comment: Got it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011149/python-variable-increment-while-loop?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

the_number = random.randrange(100) + 1
tries = 0
while True:
  tries += 1
  guess = int(raw_input("Take a guess:  "))
  if guess > the_number:
    print "Lower..."
  elif guess < the_number:
    print " Higher..."
  else:
    print "Awesome achievement, it took you", tries, "tries"
    break
```

Comment: So what exactly was I doing wrong then? I would like to really understand the theory behind what I was doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You need to put the `guess = int(raw_input(..` inside the loop, and don't break until you're done.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
import random
def main():
    secret = random.randint(1, 10)
    while (guess != secret):
    guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
        if guess > secret:
        print "too high."
        elif guess < secret:
            print "too low."
        elif guess <1 or guess > 10:
            print "invalid guess."
        elif guess == secret:
            print "You win"
            break
```

Comment: Yea I wrote it in sublime and copied it over but it didn't take the formatting over :S.  everything after define main should be indented